# Why toUpperCase() is deprecated if uppercase() is experimental?

Tags: kotlin

I got warnings telling me that `toUpperCase : String` is deprecated and that I need to use `uppercase` instead. But when using `uppercase` I have to add the `@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)` annotation. Which to me does not make sense.

Why do we have to choose between a deprecated method and an experimental one ?

Comment: What kotlin version are you using? It's not experimental on 1.6 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Kotlin version where the **uppercase** was still experimental. As of Kotlin 1.5, this is not [experimental anymore](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/uppercase.html).

To solve this, update your Kotlin to 1.5 or above.

To update Kotlin's version:

In the root `build.gradle` of your project. You will find something like this:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Change the second line to:
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'`

Comment: Thanks, but that is odd, because I'm using 1.6.10 kotlin version (with maven, not gradle). Maybe that's the IDE that went a bit wild.